# Creating json objects to exclude undefined properties

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following snippet code which, within a loop, creates a JavaScript object where some of the properties maybe undefined:

```
reader.on('record', function(record) {

    let p = record.children;
    let player = {};

    // below we create a dynamic key using an object literal obj['name'], this allows use to use
    // the id as the firebase reference id.
    player[p[0].text] = {
        id: parseInt(p[0].text, 10) || "",
        name: p[1].text || "",
        country: p[2].text || ""
    };
};
```

My question therefore; is there a better way for creating this object via a 'Map' for example? If the properties are undefined then do not add them to the object.

**Note:** This data is being sent to a Firebase DB, so any undefined values throw an error -- my crude (but working) approach is to add them as an empty string.

Here is a sample of the JSON I would like to see (notice country is not missing from the second player):

```
{
 "players" : {
    "100001" : {
      "id" : 100001,
      "name" : "Matt Webb",
      "country" : "ENG"
    },
    "100002" : {
      "id" : 100002,
      "name" : "Joe Bloggs",
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check if the properties are defined first, and then only add it if they are defined.

Comment: @PatrickEvans That's not a duplicate, that question is asking based on a separate parameter being either `true` or `false` to determine if a property should be added or not. This question is based on the value of the parameters themselves being defined.

Comment: This question cannot be answered unless you show us how the input(s) (`record`) look like. Also what are you going to do with the `player` objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` values are not set in Firebase and don't give you error

```
player[p[0].text] = {
    id: parseInt(p[0].text, 10) || null,
    name: p[1].text || null,
    country: p[2].text || null
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
player = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(player));
```

This way, you can use...

```
player[p[0].text] = {
    id: parseInt(p[0].text, 10),
    name: p[1].text,
    country: p[2].text
};
```

... and don't worry with undefined values, because JSON.stringify doesn't serialize keys with undefined values...